# How to Cancel a AlertDialogue from another method?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, runnable

I have an Alert Dialogue Box and I want it to be accessible from a runnable method. The goal is to cancel the dialogue box once it reaches a certain criteria.

Below is the code for creating the AlertDialogue:

```
public void perm_dialogue()
{
    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.permission_wifi, null);

    perm_prog = (ProgressBar)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.perm_progressBar);
    perm_text = (TextView)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.perm_text);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

    // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                            //call the delay function
                            handler1.post(DelayTask);

                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();

    perm_prog.setVisibility(promptsView.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Now this is the code I used to make the Runnable:

```
public Runnable DelayTask = new Runnable()
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        //scanning loop for 10 secs
        if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()==true)
        {
            //process
            perm_prog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //Close Alert Dialogue


            //stopHandler();
            handler1.removeCallbacks(this);
            return;

        }
        else if(k==40)
        {

            //stopHandler();

            handler1.removeCallbacks(this);
            return;

        }
        else
        {
            perm_prog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            perm_text.setText("Please Wait...");
        }
        k++;
        handler1.postDelayed(DelayTask, 250);
    }
};
```

Now in the runnable, I have placed a Comment tag indicating the place where I want to call the cancel function of the AlertDialogue.

Any Suggession will help!
Thanks!

Comment: Try this tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents

Comment: use alertDialog.dismiss();

Comment: @user3515851 alertDialogue.dismiss() cannot be fetched on another method.
How do i localize it in the runnable?

Comment: create  alertDialog a global variable (AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = null;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try as follows take AlertDialog as member variable

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{
    AlertDialog alertDialog=null;
    onCreate(-){
     }
}
```

and create dialog as follows

```
 // create alert dialog
alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
```

and then call dismiss() wherever you want in activity as

```
alertDialog.dismiss();
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Yup it helped. But another problem sufficed. It seems that weather I put a dialog.dismiss() or not.....the alert box seems to close by itself when I press the OK button.
I have not included the dialog.dismiss().
this shouldnt happen right?

Comment: If you want to cancel the dialog without interacting with dialog buttons you have to use dialog.dismiss(); but if you click on the buttons of dialog the dialog will automatically closed by itself and it will execute related listeners if implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your alertDialog a global variable, and then call alertDialog.dismiss() where you have the comment tag.